# Query result set export to local machine Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

I have a remote mongodb which I am able to connect using local mongo.

```
mongo vm-test-001:27048/itemm_db -u item_user -p Mongo12
```

And I am able to get the desired result set by running the below query

```
 db.inventory.find({ syncLastUpdatedDate: { $gte:ISODate("2017-05-26 11:12:16.138Z"), $lt: ISODate("2017-05-27 11:12:16.138Z") } })
```

But when I try to export the output into local csv  but I am unable to do it .

I am new to Mongo so if someone can help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [`--query`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-query) in the `mongoexport` documentation

Comment: Also [`Date`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#date) in the related MongoDB extended JSON manual page. Both results are easily found simply searching for ["mongodb export CSV"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+export+csv)

Comment: Thank you all .. I will able to fix it with your help